# Fill a matrix without using for()

Tags: r, matrix, random

I have a long matrix which I want to fill with `rnorm(1)` but it takes much time (unlike this sample below). Is there an alternative way since the number of rows and columns will always be equal but dynamic.

```
my <- matrix(c(0), nrow= 3, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    my[i,j]<-rnorm(1)
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do something like:

```
matrix(rnorm(500), ncol = 5)
```

Comment: my actual function is not rnorm()  but I wanted to use something simple here.

Comment: If you're function is generating data similar to `rnorm()` then it will work the same.

Comment: Numbers of cols and rows must always be the same. that generates 5 columns and 100 rows

Comment: @firmo23 If your function is vectorized than this approach will work. If your function is not vectorized then vectorize it with `Vectorize()` and this approach will work. But `Vectorize()` is just loop-hiding---if your function is slow there's no way around calling it as many times as you need. Putting numbers in a matrix is fast. Calling your function a whole lot is what is slow.

Comment: @firmo23 I just used those numbers as an example you can plug and play with what you like. As gregor said you can vectorize or you can generate how ever many values you need from your function and then just stick it in a matrix with predefined columns.